# Is stating "x standard deviations above/below the mean of y" useful without knowledge of the distribution of y?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, inference

Let's say IQ has a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15. Then IQ values that are one 1 standard deviation below and above mean correspond to IQ's between 85-100 and 100-115, respectively.

This statement and the use of standard deviations in it builds on the notion that IQ is symmetrically distributed. So, is there any reason why the standard deviation should be used without prior knowledge of a variable's distribution (e.g., IQ's)?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "inferences of this type"? The only inference you have presented so far is that $100 \pm 1\times 15 = \{85, 115\}$.  That's incontrovertible (and independent of any distributional assumptions).

Comment: @whuber. That was a mistake. See edited version.

Comment: Your edited statement does not depend on an assumption of symmetry at all. It's always true that mean $\pm$ SD is the interval mean $-$ SD to mean $+$ SD. That's nothing but the definition of $\pm$.  More positively, it's often roughly true that such an interval includes about 2/3 of the data (and for given data you can always check what the fraction is).

Comment: The idea of an SD is easiest to visualise when you have a Gaussian or normal and the SD is the distance between the mean and the positions of the inflexions of the distribution, but it's often and without too much difficulty applied to skewed distributions (e.g. Poisson, exponential).  I gather that IQ data are often roughly symmetric but that depends on who is in the sample and measurement protocols.

Comment: It's difficult to say if something is "useful" without some idea of what it's being used *for*. It might well be useful in some situations and not so useful in others.

Answer (score 4):

We need to know *something* about the distribution, but not very much.  We need to know more about what we are trying to find out and why we want the sd in the first place.

For instance, from [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Identities_and_mathematical_properties), we can know that, for any distribution that has a defined standard deviation, 75% are within 2 sd of the mean, 89% within 3 sd and 94% within 4 sd and, in general, $1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$ within k sd.

However, one could argue that, for any distribution where you would not use the mean as a measure of central tendency, you should not use the sd as a measure of spread.  But whether you should use the mean depends not only on the distribution but on your purposes.  For instance, we often use median income rather than mean, because income is quite skewed and the mean is influenced by outliers. But there are situations where the mean is appropriate for income.